# How to draw an AABB bounding box in simple c++/opengl?

Tags: opengl, visual-c++, bounding-box, aabb

I don't know how to draw a bounding box around my 3D object using visual C++/Opengl!

I have calculated min and max value of my obj, but now what do I do!?

> Update to my above post:
>   Have figured out how to draw the Bounding box! How can I align it to the axes?

Answer (score 1):

You have to generate a line-mesh (or whatever you want to display) for the bounding box. The vertices should be easy to find when you already have min and max value.

Comment: Hi BDL, thanks for your response! But like I said I'm a newbie and I did try drawing using geometric values of axis aligned x,y and z being 0. But all I get is a small triangle in the middle of my object...